# Retrieving a longblob image then upload it database

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the currently logged in user's profile picture then upload it to my chat database how do i upload it without using the input type="file"

```
<?php
session_start
$uservalue = $_SESSION['username']; //sample session value

$selectuser="select * from table where user= '$uservalue'";
$result= mysqli_query($database,$selectuser);
$row = mysqli_fecth_array($result);
```

im trying to insert the image using

```
    $name = $row['username'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO chat (name,image) values ('$name', '$image') "
```

the datatype of my image is a longblob

Comment: is this question about sql or about uploading the image?

Comment: uploading the image

Comment: so - you don't have a form or javascript and you want to upload an image without using a file input field?

Comment: logged in user has already uploaded the image, so what is the problem simply get the image URL and store it into the `chat` table.

Comment: how do you get the url if its inside the database? i don't have any folder directory im just inserting the image to the database